# Collision resistant hash function

Tags: cryptography, hash

A function is $(\varepsilon, t)$-collision resistant if there is no boolean circuit (using "not", "and", "or") of size at most $t$ which outputs a collision with probability at least $\varepsilon$.

Let $h_0:\{0,1\}^{2m}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^m$ be a $(\varepsilon, t)$-collision resistant hash function and $i\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$.
Define a hash function $h_i: \{0,1\}^{2^{i+1}\cdot m}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$ recursively using $h_{i-1}$ in the following way:
Interpret the bit string $x\in \{0,1\}^{2^{i+1}\cdot m}$ as $x=x_1 x_2$, where both $x_1,x_2\in \{0,1\}^{2^i\cdot m}$.

Then the hash value $h_i(x)$ is defined as

$$h_i(x)=h_0(h_{i-1}(x_1)h_{i-1}(x_2)).$$

For which $(\varepsilon_i, t_i)$ is $h_i$ $(\varepsilon_i, t_i)$-collision resistant?
And can we successfully use the birthday attack on this hash function to find collisions?

Comment: Welcome to CS.StackExchange!  FYI, you're more likely to get good answers to this kind of question on [Cryptography.StackExchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: By the way, Shu, may I ask: is this homework?  (It looks like something that would be a good homework problem!)  If it is homework, can you show us what you've tried so far, and where you've gotten stuck?

Answer (score 3):

The birthday attack applies to any hash-function, regardless of its structure, and also to $h_i$.

For your first question, here is a possible hint. Note that

- if we can find a collision in $h_i$ then we can find a collision in $h_0$ (by considering the top-most $h_0$, for instance).
- if we can find a collision in $h_0$ then, we can find a collision for $h_i$ (by replacing one of the inner-most $h_0$ with it's collision).

Comment: I don't really understand how I can use this hint for the $(\varepsilon, t)$-resistance proof. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: if there is a $(\epsilon,t)$-circuit that finds collision for $h_0$, then by the second claim, the same(?) circuit finds a collision for $h_i$?

Comment: What do you mean by $(\varepsilon, t)$-circuit? Doesn't $(\varepsilon, t)$-collision resistant mean that there is NO circuit of the properties stated above?

Comment: yes, $(\epsilon,t)$-resistant means there is no such circuit. So if you know $h_0$ is $(\epsilon,t)$-resistant, and you know that a circuit for $h_i$ implies a circuit for $h_0$, you can infer that $h_i$ is also $(\epsilon,t)$-resistant (assuming it is exactly the same circuit, or otherwise, change $t$ accordingly).

Comment: And how do we know (concretely) for which $(\varepsilon, t)$ the function is collision resistant?

Comment: I think you can only relate $\varepsilon_i, t_i$ (of $h_i$) to $\varepsilon,t$ of $h_0$.

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the formal details of your definition of collision-resistance: if we take it seriously, then *no* function (whose output is shorter than its input) can ever be collision-resistant.

By the pigeonhole property, it is guaranteed that *there exists* some pair of messages $x,x' \in \{0,1\}^{2m}$ such that $h_0(x)=h_0(x')$ but $x\ne x'$.  Therefore, *there exists* some circuit $C$ that outputs a collision in $h_0$ (just take the circuit that has $x$ and $x'$ hardcoded in it and that outputs $x,x'$; it will do, and it is very small, with fewer than $t$ gates for any reasonable value of $t$). Consequently, no matter what function $h_0$ you pick, it won't be collision-resistant.

Similarly, no matter what function you pick, $h_i$ will never be collision-resistant.

Therefore, the question is framed poorly.  I suspect you will want to go back to the drawing board and think more carefully about what exactly you want to know.

Comment: D.W. that's a good point. I automatically assumed we are talking about a family of hashes $\{h_0\}$ and look for a single $C$ that works for all of them. A single hash function never makes sense, almost always people actually mean a sample out of a family. But this indeed should be clarified by the OP.